# Is there a way to execute an implementation class in an order

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, structuremap

```
public interface IInterface<T>
{
 void Handle(T message);
}

public class A: IInterface<T>
{
  void Handle(T Message) {}
}

public class B: IInterface<T>
{
  void Handle(T Message) {}
}
```

Client :

```
        public void Execute<T>(T message)
        {  
            var commandHandlers = DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices(typeof(IInterface<T>)).Cast<IInterface<T>>();

// The above line will give a list of implementation class of IInterface.

            foreach (var commandHandler in commandHandlers)
            {
                commandHandler.Handle(message);
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to execute a class B implementation first and class A implementation as a second one?

Comment: Real code would be useful. The class implementations don't compile.

Comment: Can you not simply order the `commandHandlers` by their type name in descending order?

Comment: Not sure if if the DI container respects order but can't you just register Class B before A?

Answer (score 3):

You can add order property to control it:

```
public interface IInterface<T>
{
 void Handle(T message);
 int Order {get;}
}

public class A: IInterface<T>
{
  void Handle(T Message) {}
  public int Order => 1;
}

public class B: IInterface<T>
{
  void Handle(T Message) {}
  public int Order => 0;
}

foreach (var commandHandler in commandHandlers.OrderBy(o=>o.Order))
{
    commandHandler.Handle(message);
}
```